# Инкремент в функции

Tags: c++, указатели, операторы, инкремент

Доброго времени суток!

В функции должен происходить инкремент целого числа передаваемого как указатель.
Странность заключается в том что с int можно делать что угодно, только не инкремент. Сталкивался с этой проблемой и раньше и приходилось писать += вместо ++.
Объясните где собака зарыта!

Вывод:

На входе: 3

После сложения: 503

После инкремента: 7339896

На выходе: 7339896

Num: 503

Код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void TestFunc(int*);

int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    int Num = 3;

    TestFunc(&Num);
    wcout << L"Num: " << Num << endl;

    return 0;
}



void TestFunc(int* Num){

    wcout << L"На входе: " << *Num << endl;

    *Num += 500;
    wcout << L"После сложения: " << *Num << endl;

    *Num++;
    *Num++;
    *Num++;
    wcout << L"После инкремента: " << *Num << endl;

    wcout << L"На выходе: " << *Num << endl;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8208106/5308259 "*ptr++;   // Pointer moves to the next int position (as if it was an array). But returns the old content".

Comment: Спасибо Эникейщик!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос приоритета операторов.

Попробуйте написать

```
(*Num)++;
```

и все у вас получится — https://ideone.com/TmKsj8

Без скобок вы увеличиваете не значение, на которое указывает указатель, а само значение указателя.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал!

Comment: См. https://ravesli.com/urok-38-prioritet-operatsij-assotsiativnost/#toc-0

Comment: @Harry - ответ прекрасный, в стиле "краткость - сестра нашего брата"! И правда, кроме ( ) - что тут еще сказать?